# Unity, How do i use the Patroll.cs script i created ? Getting errors

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

In the Hierarchy i have Main Camera, ThirdPersonController, Plane, Terrain, Cylinder, Wall.

And in Assets i creayed a new folder called My Scripts and there i created a new script in c# called Patroll.cs, The script should mke the ThirdPersoncontroller character to walk between two given points to patroll. But when i'm adding/dragging the Patroll script to the ThirdPersonController i'm getting error:

The error is in the Patroll.cs script on the line:

```
if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
```

The error is:

MissingComponentException: There is no 'NavMeshAgent' attached to the "ThirdPersonController" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a NavMeshAgent to the game object "ThirdPersonController". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

This is the Patroll.cs script code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Patroll : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] points;
    private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).
        agent.autoBraking = false;

        GotoNextPoint();

    }

    void GotoNextPoint() {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Length == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Length;
    }


    void Update () {
        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.
        if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
            GotoNextPoint();
    }
}
```

What i tried to do then is clicked in the Hierarchy on the ThirdPersonController then in the menu i clicked on Component > Navigation > Nav Mesh Agent

Now in the ThirdPersonController in the Inspector i see the added Nav Mesh Agent.

Now when i'm running the game i'm getting the same error:

MissingComponentException: There is no 'NavMeshAgent' attached to the "ThirdPersonController" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a NavMeshAgent to the game object "ThirdPersonController". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

I tried to click in the menu on Window > Navigation and then clicked on Bake.
But it didn't solve it.

Same error on same line in the Patroll.cs script.

But i added a Nav Mesh Agent to the ThirdPersonController so why in the error it say it's not attached ? And how do i make the Agent to be enabled ?

In the ThirdPersonController after added to it the Patroll script in the Inspector i see in the Patroll part i can add points change another value but the properties: Dest Point and Agent are gray can't be used.

In the Agent i see: Agent None (Nav Mesh Agent) but i can't click on it it's gray not enabled.

UPDATE:

This is a screenshot of the ThirdPersonController Inspector on the right the Patroll script and the Nav Mesh Agent.

[image: Screenshot]

In the Patroll.cs script i changed the variable agent to be public:

```
public NavMeshAgent agent;
```

Now the ThirdPersonController have the Nav Mesh Agent and the Patroll script in the Inspector and i also added as agaent in the patroll: ThirdPersonController (Nav Mesh Agent) but now i'm getting the error:

"GetRemainingDistance" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.
UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:get_remainingDistance()
Patroll:Update() (at Assets/My Scripts/Patroll.cs:41)

Line 41 in the patroll script is:

```
if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure that `NavMeshAgent` is attached to the-same GameObject `Patroll` is attached to?

Comment: @Programmer If attached meaning dragging the script ot the object then yes. The Nav Mesh Agent and the script in both ThirdPersonController.

Comment: @Programmer i added a screenshot to my question you can see the ThirdPersonController Inspector on the right the Patroll script and the Nav Mesh Agent on same object. And you can see the Agent in the Patroll script in the Inspector is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not assigned a `NavMeshAgent` component containing object in your `Patroll` script component.

[image]

Agent variable field should be public or serializeable private.

```
public NavMeshAgent Agent;
```

Comment: Ok i changed the variable to be public. Now in the ThirdPersonController i have the script Patroll.cs and the Nav Mesh Agent. In the Inspector i added to the Patroll to the Agent: ThirdPersoncontroller (Nav Mesh Agent) but still when running the game i'm getting the error "GetRemainingDistance" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh. It's on line 41 in the Patroll.cs script: if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)

Comment: In your scene click on a mesh or terrain and then in Window tabs select navigation... Now you can see navigation layout beside the inspector... Just in bake tab of navigation click the bottom button that says Bake... And you're done!

Comment: Tried it now same erorr "GetRemainingDistance" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh. Strange. I updated my question with a new screenshot showing the thirdpersoncontroller inspector. and now i baked it after clicked on Terrain but same error.

Comment: Terrain is static?

Comment: First, the NavMeshAgent needs to be enabled in the inspector. Then, there needs to be a baked navmesh in the scene. And finally, the agent needs to be somewhat close to the navmesh.

Comment: Terrain is not static. The Nav Mesh Agent is enabled you can see in the second screenshot i added in the inspector it's enabled. How do you bake the navmeshagent ? I clicked on Terrain and then Windows > Navigation and on the bake tab clicked the button bake. And how do you move the agent to be close to the navmesh ? They are both in the thirdpersoncontroller object.

Comment: Set terrain static. And bake terrain again.

Comment: Ok set it to static and baked now the bake was working. Now when running the game the character move to the walls(the building) and there it's stuck walking on very small area from side to side and everything is stuttering. I gave in the inspector in the patroll as way points: Walls (Transform) and Cylinder (Transform). I wanted it to walk not only move to the walls and then to the cylinder. Strange.

Comment: You can see in this very short video clip i made how the character is moving in my unity: https://youtu.be/cd6Cbo7zzoQ

Comment: http://noobtuts.com/content/unity/tower-defense-game/navigation_properties.png Edit radius and height

Comment: So… My answer will solve your error problem. You can ask another question if you are still having problems just like the error above.